# what are the Nvidia video card compatible with ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, video, hardware, vga

what are the Nvidia video card compatible with ubuntu 12.04 64bit? 
Could you provide the list of compatible Nvidia video cards with ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see full list  [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsNvidia) or can find Your device [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/make/NVIDIA%20Corporation/?page=1)

Comment: The full list didn't mention any card for ubuntu 12.04 do you have a newer list?. I found in the second list but the card are old so what shall i do?! thanks in advance for your help

Comment: sorry to that, I can't find other list. Maybe workaround is to search about particular video card information and issues in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What for do you need this list? Are you thinking about buying a new nvidia graphics card?

Comment: most nvidia cards work in ubuntu, except those with Optimum technology, that is not fully supported yet. I would avoid state of the art cards at the moment.

Comment: Thats 'Optimus' not 'Optimum' - leousa.