# I've given up on NVIDIA in Ubuntu 64bit 12.04. What graphics cards are stable?

Tags: 12.04, graphics, hardware

I can't handle any more crashes. I have tried many different fixes to the NVIDIA driver problem but none of them work. This goes to show that open video drivers are paramount to Linux.

**What other stable graphics cards are there that will run on ubuntu 12.04?**

I am currently using NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560. Once I have a good alternative I will speak with my pocket book and return my NVIDIA card and not look back to NVIDIA until they adequately support Linux.

Comment: Have you tried the driver from “Ubuntu-X” team? `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

Comment: Yes. And I just tried it again and I have tried what is mentioned in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140760/ubuntu-12-04-nvidia-gtx-460-video-card-installation. The error I get from firefox includes: OpenGL: NVIDIA Corporation -- GeForce GTX 560/PCIe/SSE2 -- 4.2.0 NVIDIA 295.53 -- texture_from_pixmap

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/134280

Comment: The list referenced 'in what are the Nvidia video card compatible with ubuntu 12.04 64bit' [The hardware list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsNvidia) has not been updated for three years. Does this make sense? The graphics cards referenced are dated. Is there another updated list? Perhaps the latest Nvidia cards would work but they are about us $400. I would simply like to have a graphics card that wont crash 40% of the time I open a web browser that has any video on it. I tried using flash aid and other extensions but they still crash with nvida error.

Comment: I am returning my video card. I hope the next one works. It is sort of a shot in the dark for me not knowing a reliable and quality graphics card. It seems to me that ubuntu could make some money from links to products that are actually tested and are shown to work for the latest releases.

Comment: Ant:
How many monitors are you running with the Radeon HD 6870?
What resolution are each of your monitors?
Which ports are each of the monitors plugged into?
Are you using any active dvi dual-link to DisplayPort adaptors? In looking at the 6870,
http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/graphics/2010/10/22/ati-radeon-hd-6870-review/3
it looks like one of the dvi out's is dual-link.
So if using hi res monitors (above 1,920 x 1,200) one would have to use both mini DisplayPorts with active adaptors and the dvi dual-link port.

Comment: I realize that this issue is solved, but just in case if someone will hit this thread while searching if NVidia is ok to use with Linux or not: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MZs3MQO5eU

Answer (score 2):

I have nvidia 304.51 working fine. I had problems like you did but found upgrading my kernel first to 3.5.0.17, and then installed the nvidia, solved my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I returned the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 card and bought a RADEON HD 6870 card. I still had trouble until I reinstalled from scratch. It now works like a charm. I still think there is some trouble with Nvidia cards in Ubuntu 12.04. This is the first time I have had trouble with NVIDIA.

Thanks Richand and fossfreedom for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 completely installed with GeForce GTX560 Ti

I had a similar problem but it was happening after an update.
Before everything was working fine.

Bugfix in terminal:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings

No everything works fine again.
Somehow it looks like that my openjdk-7 was not able to do an driver upgrade for
my nvidia card.
Before I had set my AdditionalDrivers setting to "POST-RELEASE UPDATES" but now I 
switched back to "VERSION CURRENT" to avoid future problems.